# Drone ESC causes motor to twitch and beep when powered and PWM signal applied

Tags: batteries, motor, pic, motor-controller, drone

I'm trying to make a drone from scratch, and have bought four of [these ESCs and motors](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/133806781816?var=433253146035) from Ebay. Now, I've got one of the ESCs hooked up to a 7.4V lipo battery, and the 3 pin cable running to a PIC microcontroller (specifically a PIC18F45k22, with the white PWM wire attached to the PWM4 pin).

The code running on the microcontroller should be simply ramping the PWM signal from 0-1024 and back again in a loop, and it does indeed do that as I can see when I attach an LED to the PWM4 pin.

The problem is, when a motor is attached to the ESC and I plug the battery in, the motor starts beeping loudly every second or so, and twitching.

I thought it might be that the battery was low, so I plugged it into the charger and it was pretty much full.

I presume that the reason this is happening is because I'm not properly arming the ESC, and the ebay listing does specify that this ESC needs to be armed, but it just does not specify *how*. Does anyone have any ideas as to how I might achieve this?

Comment: I ran into similar issues building an RC device with a gyroscope - cheap ones without decent instructions wind up making me wish I'd just have spent more for a good one.

Comment: @JYelton yeah, I'm kind of thinking the same thing, but these didn't even seem that cheap to be fair
Did you find a solution in the end?

Comment: `does indeed do that as I can see when I attach an LED to the PWM4 pin` ... you can't know for sure ... use an oscilloscope

Comment: @jsotola unfortunately I don't have my oscilloscope at the moment, I left it at university and am currently not there. I can be fairly sure that the PWM signal is being produced though, since the LED which I attached brightens and dims accordingly

Comment: You may have the PWM working, but is the period correct for that ESC?  Most (all?) RC servos use a 20ms period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hobby ESC's expect a 'servo PWM' signal, which has a 20ms period and a 'pulse width' centered at 1500us which has variable range (but you can typically expect somewhere in the ballpark of 1000us to 2000us). That means a typical hobbyist ESC will parse an input duty of 10% at 50Hz as a request for ~100% duty cycle motor control output. Some also have arbitrary, undocumented requirements for a signal pattern on startup (ramping up from zero and then back down, then idling for some amount of time...). Error and status information are typically delivered by using the motor stator as a voice coil (beeps) and since documentation is also universally scarce, most of the time you're pretty much just expected to intuit what those beeps mean.

You didn't explicitly say this, but I'm inferring that 'ramping the PWM signal from 0-1024 and back again in a loop' (and your mention of testing this using an LED) means you've set your PWM peripheral up with an arbitrarily selected period, such that a CCPR value of 1024 corresponds to 100% PWM. This is probably putting your ESC in an error state, since you're giving it a signal that isn't compliant with the 'hobbyist standard'. You should set it up to deliver the proper signal profile, and verify with an oscilloscope if it doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems correct. I'll experiment this evening and try and get it working. That's pretty cool that it uses the motor's stator for the beeping
And yes, you are correct that I arbitrarily selected the period for my PWM.

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to set up the PWM peripheral so that 1024 is only 10%? The ebay seller of the ESC sent me a video showing that to arm the ESC I need to put the throttle to highest (so, 10% duty), and then wait for three beeps, then put it to lowest (which I assume is 0%). Some experimenting shows me that 10% duty is a value of 30 in my code. If I set it to 30, the motor does the 3 beeps I would expect, but then after that when I set it to 0 it doesn't do the next expected part of the procedure. Here's the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BnE-tOJ8RDg

Comment: 0% is likely not the lowest, and 10% might not be the highest. You may want to use two timers, one set up to do a single pulse, and one to give you a 20ms period. You also aren't relegated to only 10 bits of PWM resolution afaik, PIC18 has 16 bit resolution timer modules